# Google Maps API v3 client-side tiling?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, client-side

I am using the Google Maps API v3 with a custom 6000x6000 pixel map image, originally about 6MB of disk space. After I used a program to create tiles compatible with Google Maps, I got about 5,300 tiles totaling around 120MB of disk space. Viewing the map online is incredibly slow because those tiles have to be downloaded from the server each time. Is there a way to make it so the client downloads the original 6MB 6000x6000 map PNG then creates tiles client-side as needed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your own tiling programm. Google uses a z morton curve to subdivide the map. A z morton curve is really simple and it's only some bit shift. But you need the client permission to download a file? So, no.

Comment: The map has already been tiled and the tiles are stored on the server, so when someone looks at the map they automatically download the tiles. The problem is, there are about 5,300 of them and it takes a long time to download them all so the map is very slow. I was wondering if there was some sort of way, maybe JavaScript or something, where the main 6000x6000 pixel image (6MB) is downloaded then maybe there could be some sort of way to write in JavaScript a tiling function which automatically does the tiling as needed. I don't know if this sort of thing is possible though.

Comment: @spotter12: No, it's not. When you already have tiles it's the best possible. If you want to reduce better you need vector based maps and not tile based map. OpenMap is vector based.